# Regular expression - capture number between underscores within a sequence between commas

Tags: sql, regex, datagrip, exasol

I have a field in a database table in the format:

```
111_2222_33333,222_444_3,aaa_bbb_ccc
```

This is format is uniform to the entire field. Three underscore separated numeric values, a comma, three more underscore separated numeric values, another comma and then three underscore separated text values. No spaces in between

I want to extract the middle value from the second numeric sequence, in the example above I want to get **444**

In a SQL query I inherited, the regex used is `^.,(\d+)_.$` but this doesn't seem to do anything.

I've tried to identify the first comma, first number after and the following underscore `,222_` to use as a starting point and from there get the next number without the `_` after it

This `(,\d*_)(\d+[^_])` selects `,222_444` and is the closest I've gotten

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: The need for you to tag with your database is that each DB has very different string and regex APIs.

Comment: If you are able to get ,222_444 just remove the first round brackets for first group and you should round up with 444 as you required 

,\d*_(\d+[^_])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` with a capture group:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE( 
        '111_2222_33333,222_444_3,aaa_bbb_ccc',
        '^[^,]+,[^_]+_(.*?)_[^_]+,.*$',
        '\1') AS num
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is a demo showing that the above regex' first capture group contains the quantity you want.

### Demo